# How asp.net core restapi to support List<item> with IFormFile

Tags: asp.net, .net, rest, asp.net-core

This is the model I have created. Here I need to pass a list along with the IFormFile.

```
public class RequestModel
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Description{ get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a file.")]
    [AllowedExtensions(new[] {".zip", ".rar", ".tar", ".gz"})]
    public IFormFile File{ get; set; }

    public List<Input> FileInputs { get; set; }
}


public class Input
{
    public string InputName { get; set; }
    public string Scope { get; set; }
    public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
}
```

Adding api below

```
[HttpPost("saveFile")]
     public ApiResponse SaveFile([FromForm]  RequestModel Model){
    SaveToDB(Model);
    }
```

Now I'm not getting the FileInputs to the api, the FileInputs count is getting as 0, when I execute the code below

```
var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:5000/api/saveFile");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1laWQiOiJTcnV0aGlKUyIsIm5iZiI6MTY0NTUyNzcwMiwiZXhwIjoxNjQ2MTMyNTAyLCJpYXQiOjE2NDU1Mjc3MDJ9.pX9dtITSWobXejK41ojpM25j1QkGp5tx1QjyfSvmu5M1l7lznTVjN1aLgjS5WbFt8eeJ3-INm_Z0s5NEXkC9fw");
request.AddFile("File", "/C:/Downloads/SampleFile.zip");
request.AddParameter("Name", "mollit laborum elit dolor");
request.AddParameter("Description", "File uploadng");
request.AddParameter("FileInputs", "[{\"inputName\":\"dolore ea\",,\"scope\":\"nulla ut\",\"isRequired\":false},{\"inputName\":\"Excepteur\",\"scope\":\"irure amet deserunt\",\"isRequired\":false}]");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

after executing this, I can save all details except FileInputs to db.

Answer (score 0):

The data of  Input get value from body  by Default,and web api project can't use [FromBody] and [FromForm] in the same action,so I suggest use custom modelbinder  to get the value of Input object
Custom modelbinder:

```
public class CusBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var a = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (a != ValueProviderResult.None)
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(bindingContext.ModelName, a);
            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };
            var deserialized = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(a.FirstValue, bindingContext.ModelType, options);
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(deserialized);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Model:

```
[ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(CusBinder))]
    public class Input
    {
        public string InputName { get; set; }
        public string Scope { get; set; }
        public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
    }
```

And you need to modify your client side codes as follow：

```
var client = new RestClient("https://localhost:44348/WeatherForecast/saveFile");
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1laWQiOiJTcnV0aGlKUyIsIm5iZiI6MTY0NTUyNzcwMiwiZXhwIjoxNjQ2MTMyNTAyLCJpYXQiOjE2NDU1Mjc3MDJ9.pX9dtITSWobXejK41ojpM25j1QkGp5tx1QjyfSvmu5M1l7lznTVjN1aLgjS5WbFt8eeJ3-INm_Z0s5NEXkC9fw");
            request.AddFile("File", "yourfilepath");
            request.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true;            
            request.AddParameter("Name", "mollit laborum elit dolor");
            request.AddParameter("Description", "File uploadng");
            request.AddParameter("FileInputs", "{\"inputName\":\"dolore ea\",\"scope\":\"nulla ut\",\"isRequired\":false}");
            request.AddParameter("FileInputs", "{\"inputName\":\"Excepteur\",\"scope\":\"irure amet deserunt\",\"isRequired\":false}");
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Result:

[image: Result]